# Specific Annotations changes required in plotly graph

Tags: css, r, plotly

i have dataset[image: Given dataset]

Here is my code.Using this code i have plotted a graph [image: The given plotly graph produced using this code].But what i want is specific annotations for specific severity like change of arrowsize and font for the count which are in critical severity range or applying different font to different severity range without any change to other data points  so that it will remain highlighted.Example[image: The result should be somewhat like this,without any change in other data points in the graph]

```
input_file$Severity  <- factor(input_file$Severity , levels =c("Critical","Moderate", "Major","High","Low"))
cols <- c("#F72E03", "#08EE71", "#B7273F","#28E5EE","#188A4C")
m <- list(l = 100,r = 50, b = 200,t = 10,pad = 0)
t <- list(family = "sans serif",size = 14,color = 'blue')
ax <- list(showticklabels = TRUE,zeroline=TRUE,showline=T,showgrid=T)
ay <- list(showticklabels = TRUE,zeroline=TRUE,showline=T,showgrid=T)`
plot_ly(input_file, x =~Category, y =~Severity,type="scatter",color=~Severity,colors=cols,mode="markers",marker=list(size=15,width=2))%>%
layout(xaxis=ax,yaxis=ay,font=t)%>%
layout(margin=m)%>%
add_annotations(x = input_file$Category,
              y = input_file$Severity,
              text = input_file$count,
              textangle = -45,
              xref = "x",
              yref = "y",
              showarrow = T,
              arrowhead = 4,
              arrowsize = .5,
              ax = 20,
              ay = -40,
              # Styling annotations' text:
              font = list(color = '#264E86',
                          family = 'Comic Sans MS',
                          size = 12))
```

Comment: Hover over the R tag - it asks for a aminimal reproducible example. You provided neither one nor the other.

Comment: hovering is present but i want to highlight the data which are critical in different style so that it is different from others.

Comment: I meant "hover over the R tag under your post and read its tooltip". :-) _"object 'input_file' not found"_. Providing a minimal reproducible example increases chances of getting answers. (Not many have the time and the leisure to create something from scratch.)

Comment: input_file is the name of the file after reading the given csv file.If you create a csv file with these data,then use input_file<-read.csv("finaldestination.csv") it will not show the error "object 'input_file' not found"

Comment: It's on you to provide the data. It belongs to a good question. Can be dummy data or whatever. However, should be enough to recreate your chart. Everything else is inefficient. Obviously noone has the time to _"create a csv file with these data"_,